# SQL Server 2005 Tools makes SQL Server 2008 Express install fail

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, installation, sql-server-express

When I tried installing SQL Server 2008 Express, the install failed due to this line.  How can I circumvent this, or fix the issue?

[image]

Comment: Uninstall SQL Server 2005 Express tools? Or SQL Server 2005 Express completely? Do you need to keep both?

Comment: I can't see them listed in Programs and Features

Answer (score 4):

1. Open Run Menu and type `regedit`.
2. It will open Registry Editor
3. Now go to following location.

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > Software > Wow6432Node > Microsoft > Microsoft SQL Server > 90
   ```
4. Right click on `90` and click on Delete.
5. Press Yes to confirm deletion.

Now try to install SQL Server 2008 and it would work this time.

Answer (score 2):

For the features you've selected (not shown), you'll need to uninstall the 2005 tools before you can proceed.

Attempting to circumvent this by some means will probably result in a corrupt installation -- why did the SQL team add a rule check specifically for this case? Best to not mess around with it...

Note that the text in the Status column is clickable, and it will tell you more specific information for each rule check.

Comment: I didn't see SQL Server 2005 listed anywhere under Programs and Features.  How can I uninstall them if I can't see them?

Comment: @MacGyver: Did you have the tools installed at some point in the past?

Comment: Not sure.  This is a beta testing machine used by our department.  Possibly.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep your old installation, you can unselect Express Tools from the Feature Selection menu. Just remove all managment tools and rerun validations.

Comment: I don't know that this is a good idea, since the older version of the tools will have difficulty managing features in the newer version of the engine.

Comment: Not really because you just install an Express version which is already a version with less feature.

Comment: I think you missed my point. *shrug*